# How do I declare device capabilities for this app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have created app with iOS 8.0 and later versions.

In app store, 
Compatibility : Compatible with iPhone 5s, 6, 6+, 6s, 6s+ and iPad…

Why iPhone 4, 4s and 5 are not available in compatibility list,but app is available in Appstore for iPhone 4, 4s and 5 and not able to download app from app store in iPhone 4s with iOS 9.2.1

```
info.plist  -
Required Device Capabilities   Array    (1 Item)
        item 0          String       armv7

Architecture  -
Valid Architectures     arm64, armv7, armv7s
```

Thank you for your suggestion

Comment: Is  it about the screen size? how do you set the screen size in the code?

Comment: My guess is that it has something to do with 64-bit devices, as iPhone 5s had A7, the first 64-bit processor (arm64) for iPhones. Though from your info.plist I'm not sure which setting is preventing it.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the top folder for your app. It takes you to a screen that will have general, capabilities, resource tags, info, ect. at the top. The first two tabs may include a capability(in capabilities) or minimum iOS update(in general) that the phone must be able to support. An older phone such as the iPhone 4 can't support iOS 9 which is the default.